# Is $p \vee q \leq p+q$ for $p,q$ projections?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, von-neumann-algebras

I am wondering if $p \vee q \leq p+q$ for $p,q$ projections acting on some Hilbert space $H$.

In particular, I wonder if the set of finite trace projections is upwards directed with the usual ordering of positive elements.

Comment: However, I think (don't have proof handy) if $p$ and $q$ are finite rank then there exists $c>0$ such that $p\lor q\leq c(p+q)$.  Not true in the infinite rank case.

Answer (score 1):

To your first question, let 
$$
p=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ q=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then 
$$
p\vee q=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ p+q=\begin{bmatrix}3/2&1/2\\1/2&1/2\end{bmatrix},
$$
so 
$$
p+q-p\vee q=\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1/2\\1/2&-1/2\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is not positive nor negative, so $p\vee q$ and $p+q$ are not comparable.

To your second question: yes, the set of projections is a lattice, i.e. in general 
$$
p\wedge q\leq p,q\leq p\vee q.
$$
And, if $p$ and $q$ are finite-rank (equivalently, finite-trace), then so is $p\vee q$.

Comment: If $pq=qp$,  $p\vee q=p+q-pq$. How to calculate $p\vee q$ in the general case?

Comment: If you mean a formula, you can't.

Comment: In the above example, how to calculate $p\vee q$?

Comment: By using the definition. The symbols "$p\vee q$" mean *the projection onto the subspace generated by the union of the ranges of $p$ and $q$*. Here the range of $p$ is the span of $e_1$ and the range of $q$ is the span of $e_1+e_2$. As these two vectors form a basis, they span all of $\mathbb C^2$, so $p\vee q$ is the identity.